# Possible ranks of a matrix

Tags: matrices, permutations

Let $v=(a_1,\cdots,a_n)$ be a real row vector. We may form the $n! \times n$ matrix $M$ whose rows are obtained by permuting the entiers of $v$ in all possible ways. The rows can be listed in an arbitrary order. Thus if $n=3$, $M$ might be $$\begin{pmatrix} a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\ a_1 & a_3 & a_2\\ a_2 & a_3 & a_1 \\ a_2 & a_1 & a_3 \\ a_3 & a_1 & a_2 \\ a_3 & a_2 & a_1\end{pmatrix}$$

Determine the possible ranks that such a matrix could have.

Comment: It is a bit of fun to find values of $a_1,a_2,a_3$ where the rank ends up 0,1 or 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rank can be 3 at maximum since there are only 3 columns. If you let $a_1=1$, $a_2 = a_3 = 0$, then this rank is attained as there will be 3 linearly independent rows.

Comment: Can your statement by generalized for n ? i.e. when we consider a $n! \times n$ matrix the rank is at most n ?

Comment: Yes, in exactly the same way.

Comment: The rank of a matrix of dimensions $m \times n$ is at most $\min(m,n)$.

Comment: right since for n>1, n<n!, then rk(A)<n

Comment: $\le n$. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: So the possible ranks are $0,1, n-1$ and $n$

Comment: Well, it is straightforward to show that ranks $0,1, n$ are attainable.

Comment: Umm, why the downvote after 6 years?

Answer (score 0):

Have:Rank(A)= Row rank of (A) = column rank of (A).So it is clear that Rank of that matrix(of order $ n!*n $) $\le n$.Now take $v=(1,0,0....0) \in R^n$ and make the required matrix.Then  you get exactly $n$ linearly independent columns. so the Rank is n.